# Trying to get property of non-object error on page with laravel eloquent (showing vendors email)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to echo out vendors email, with `{{$product->vendor->email}}` but its not working.
The vendors and Products model database structure has been screenshot

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="10%">ID#</th>
                            <th>Product Title</th>
                            <th>Vendor In charge</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->title}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->vendor->email}}</td>
                            <td>{{$settings[0]->currency_sign}}{{$product->price}}</td>
                            <td>
                                {{\App\Category::where('id',$product->category[0])->first()->name}}<br>
                                @if($product->category[1] != "")
                                {{\App\Category::where('id',$product->category[1])->first()->name}}<br>
                                @endif
                                @if($product->category[2] != "")
                                    {{\App\Category::where('id',$product->category[2])->first()->name}}
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if($product->status == 1)
                                    Active
                                @elseif($product->status == 2)
                                    Pending
                                @else
                                    Inactive
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

This is the vendor model and the ![database structure] https://i.postimg.cc/MHnwgHCz/vendormain.png

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Vendors extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public $table = "vendor_profiles";
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'gender', 'email', 'shop_name', 'photo', 'phone', 'password', 'fax', 'address', 'city', 'zip', 'current_balance', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id');
    }
}
```

This is the products model and the ![database structure] https://i.postimg.cc/W4F61ZpS/productmain.png

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'category', 'tags', 'description','sizes', 'price', 'previous_price', 'stock', 'feature_image', 'policy', 'featured', 'views', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'status'];

    public static $withoutAppends = false;


    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendors', 'vendorid');
    }

}
```

**My Error:**

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: If all products are supposed to have vendors, you may wish to add a not null constraint to your `vendorid` column

Comment: your category is a string, not array. So you  can not use  `$product->category[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have invalid value (null) so just add condition to check it

```
<td>@if(is_null($product->vendorid)) No Vendor @else {{$product->vendor->email}} @endif</td>
```

Comment: Hey @DoubleAsam ! If this solved your issue, make sure to make the answer as accepted so future visitors can benefit from the experience!